# Добавить символ плюс в маску

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Составил регулярное выражение,но не соображу, как добавить символ плюса вначале.

```
phone: /^([0-9])?(\s)?(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3}(\-)?)(\s)?[0-9]{3}(\s|\-)?[0-9]{4}(\s|\sext|\sx)?(\s)?[0-9]*$/
```

Маска для номера телефона.

Comment: А просто добавить \+ в начале уже не помогает?

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin, симвло + получается обязательным. Нужно необязательным его сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
phone: /^\+?([0-9])?(\s)?(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3}(\-)?)(\s)?[0-9]{3}(\s|\-)?[0-9]{4}(\s|\sext|\sx)?(\s)?[0-9]*$/
```

знак вопроса после символа + означает что он не обязательный